# Filtering data in controller

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to filter my data inside of my controller:

```
MyApp.controller( 'MyCtrl', [ '$scope', '$filter', function( $scope, $filter )
{
    $scope.elements = // array data;

    $scope.filterByUserSetting = function( element )
    {
        // return true/false depending on whether filter criterion matches
        // this part is fine
    }

     $scope.elementsFiltered = $filter("filterByUserSetting")($scope.elements);
    // this part doesn't work
}]);
```

The error message I get is:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.12/$injector/unpr?p0=filterByUserSettingFilterProvider%20%3C-NaNilterByUserSettingFilter at Error (native)...
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Create your filter in conventional way , like `app.filter` , look: http://plnkr.co/edit/c4hA6f877YyGXj7mkVTb?p=preview

Comment: Just answered another question where the filter was incorrectly defined as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478433/tabset-prevents-table-update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  need to define the filter provider, like

```
angular.module('MyApp', []).
    filter('filterByUserSetting', function() {
      return function(input) {
        // your return, based on your filter logic
      };
    });
```

And then use it in your controller

```
$scope.elementsFiltered = $filter( "filterByUserSetting" )( $scope.elements )
```